# Can I travel from UK to Europe with a Schengen visa received in India?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, indian-citizens, europe

I would be applying for a Schengen visa from India, specifically the Swiss visitor visa. I would be in the UK when I plan to visit Switzerland. As a holder of an Indian passport with a Schengen visa, can I travel to Switzerland and other European countries from the UK?

Comment: What will the travel plan that you submit when you apply for your visa say about your proposed itinerary?

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen Visa allows you to enter and leave the Schengen Area at any permitted border point while the visa is valid.

The Schengen Border Code contains no provisions for the restriction to a specific border point (or to/from a specific country).

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean it is allowed to travel from UK to Europe with a valid Schengen visa?

Comment: @SanthoshSundar As long as you use a a valid border point, yes. You are not allowed to take a raft a attempt to cross the channel with it.

Comment: If your Schengen Visa was issued by the Swiss Embassy you obviously submitted a travel plan that had Switzerland as main destination. I would keep it like that. Even if your travel over land (and for example via France) the first border guard you encounter my quiz you, and if your actualy plans deviate to much from what you submitted with your visa application you may be refused entry.